# On $\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} {\frac{\tan(t-t_0)}{\cosh^2(t-t_0)} \cos(\omega t) \,\mathrm{d}t}$

Tags: fourier-analysis, complex-analysis, integration

How to count this?
$$ \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} {\frac{\tan(t-t_0)}{\cosh^2(t-t_0)} \cos(\omega t) \,\mathrm{d}t} $$
Can we use residue formula?

Comment: How did this question arise?  What have you tried?

Comment: Dear Carnahan, this is a problem from my firend. It seems to be coming from a physical problem.

Comment: $\tan(t - t_0)$ has a non-integrable singularity whenever $t - t_0$ is an odd multiple of $\pi/2$. In what sense are you considering this integral?

Comment: It doesn't matter. We can consider it with Cauchy principal value.